# Beatiful Soup tbody extraction

Tags: python, extract

I am trying to extract datas from tbody from a web page.I can access the tbody part but there is a empty query came. How can I solve this? Thanks.
My expected output like there is tr and td has got in this tbody but nothing came just this : `<tbody class="matchCentreStatsContainer"></tbody>`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Abs_Conc = []
url = 'https://www.premierleague.com/match/46605'
res = requests.get(url)
html_page = res.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')

try:
    Tbody = soup.find('div', {'class': 'matchCentre'}).find('section', {'class': 'mcContent'}).find('div', {'class': 'centralContent'}).find('div', {'class': 'mcTabsContainer'}).find('section', {'class': 'mcMainTab head-to-head'}).find('div', {'class': 'mcStatsTab statsSection season-so-far wrapper col-12'}).select('tbody', {'class': 'matchCentreStatsContainer'})
```

Comment: Kabasakai `<tbody>` is generated by JS. If you access html there is no data in this tag `<tbody class="matchCentreStatsContainer"></tbody>`

Comment: Okey then is there way to access?

Comment: yes you need to run JS on page then switch to generated content and get you data

Comment: Thanks a lot but i dont understand how i gonna do it run JS on page?

Comment: for this better use selenium package

Comment: I try seleniu before it did not worked

Comment: Can you update the question with the expected output, as in the page source, nothing is after the 'matchCentreStatsContainer', so this would explain an empty query.

Comment: I updated it, i cant extract the tr or td in this tbody which i saw on the page

Comment: Can you explain in more details what you need the output to be? As to me it still is not clear. 

I understand the output given by this code, as you only request the line itself.

Comment: https://www.premierleague.com/match/46605 in this url like i wanna take Liverpool Possession rate but i cant(stats tab)

Answer (score 0):

Try this Selenium Script, it gave me a list with the stats:

```
    # Import libraries

    from selenium import webdriver 
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait  
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC  
    from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException 
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

    # Add incognito argument to webdriver
    liv_option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    liv_option.add_argument(' — incognito')

    # Request URL
    liv_browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= '/Users/Chrome/chromedriver.exe', 
                          chrome_options=liv_option) #check your correct path here!!
    liv_browser.get('https://www.premierleague.com/match/46605')

    #first click the tab 'stats'
    liv_timeout = 20 #time out, to load the page properly
    try:
       WebDriverWait(liv_browser,
              liv_timeout).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mainContent"]/div/section/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[3]'))).click()

       print("Successfully opened in the browser!")
    except TimeoutException:
       print('Page took too long to load or there was a different problem :(')
       _browser.quit()  

    #now get the needed element
    try:    
      liv = liv_browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="mainContent"]/div/section/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/section[3]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody')
      liv_stats = [x.text for x in liv]

    except:
      print('this element can not be found')

    #get the output (a list)
    liv_stats
```

Comment: This try not working and i dont understand how can i click button in BeatifulSoup

Comment: Updated the answer with a script in Selenium. It worked for me, you just need to clean the list afterwards to get the result you want.

Comment: I do not think you can use Beautiful soup to click on a button, as it is an HTML parser. I have checked if I could find something for you with Beautiful soup, maybe you can try a request. But have you tried my Selenium script? Did it work for you?